# What ports are used by Azure publish

Tags: azure, publish, ports

We have a handover for Azure project. The application will be later maintained in a corporate network and customer is now asking what ports are used by Azure.

As far a I know the control panel is basic TCP/IP + HTTP, but how about publish? I tried to Google, but only thing I found was about Web Deploy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what do you mean by "what ports are used by Azure".

If you are asking what ports you must have opened in an internal infrastructure to be able to use, deploy, monitor Windows Azure Application, the answer is 80 & 443 - the standard HTTP/HTTPS (tcp/ip) ports.

All and any manipulations of an Azure service is being done either via the Windows Azure Developer Portal or via a Management REST Services (all over HTTP/HTTPS).

(Web Deploy is just a single part, used only for Web Roles and is something that a typical Windows Azure application can live without it).

If you are asking what ports can your application use, being deployed in Windows Azure - any TCP/IP port. UDP is not supported in Windows Azure yet.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re publishing through a firewall from VS web deploy, you might need to open port 8172.

You can find here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2012/02/07/azure-ports.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx